# Prove Inequality $1-\frac{x^2}{6}<\frac{x\sin x}{2-2\cos x}<1$

Tags: inequality

I encounter this equality when doing squeeze theorem, and it is provided, but I still wonder how it can be proved. (The question doesn't say it will hold for all $x$)
$$1-\frac{x^2}{6}<\frac{x\sin x}{2-2\cos x}<1$$
Thank you for help.

Comment: They don't seem to be true for any real $x$. Did you forgot to mention a range?

Comment: @Atticus I don't know whether it is true for all real $x$. But, I checked and found that it is true for $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$, i.e. $0.817229\lt 0.906899\lt 1$..

Comment: @Atticus The question doesn't give information on that, and I think orangeskid provides a good answer already. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

The middle term can be transformed into $\frac{x}{2} \cot \frac{x}{2}$. The Taylor expansion of this function is 
$$\frac{x}{2} \cot \frac{x}{2}=1 - \frac{x^2}{12} - \frac{x^4}{720} - \frac{x^6}{30240} - \frac{x^8}{1209600} - \cdots $$
all coefficients after the first being negative. Therefore we have 
$$\frac{x}{2} \cot \frac{x}{2}<1-\frac{x^2}{12}$$ for $x \ne 0$, $|x|< 2\pi$.

Note that $\frac{x}{2} \cot \frac{x}{2}$ approaches $-\infty$ as $x \to \pm 2\pi$ from $0$. Therefore, the inequality on $LHS$ should be valid only on a smaller interval. The maximal value of $|x|$ seems to be almost $5$.

To get the LHS inequality on a smaller interval, rewrite 
$$\frac{x}{2} \cot \frac{x}{2} = \frac{x}{2} \csc
\frac{x}{2} \cdot \cos\frac{x}{2}$$
Now for $|x|< 2\pi$ we have the Taylor expansion
$$\frac{x}{2} \csc\frac{x}{2}= 1 + \frac{x^2}{24} + \frac{7 x^4}{5760} + \cdots$$
with all coefficients positive. Therefore we have
$$\frac{x}{2} \csc \frac{x}{2} > 1 + \frac{x^2}{24}$$
Moreover, we have
$$\cos \frac{x}{2} > 1 - \frac{x^2}{8}$$. From here we should be able to get the LHS on a convenient interval. For instance, for $|x|\le \pi $ we have $\cos \frac{x}{2}\ge 0$. Therefore, we get
$$\frac{x}{2} \cot \frac{x}{2}>(1 + \frac{x^2}{24})(1 - \frac{x^2}{8})= 1-\frac{x^2}{12} -\frac{x^4}{192} $$

For reference purposes:

$$1-\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^4}{12}< x \cot x < 1-\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^4}{45}$$
RHS on the pointed interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, LHS on a pointed interval containing $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Numerical testing suggests that LHS can be improved to $1-\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^4}{34}$   ($34$ works, $35$ does not!).

Comment: Please check the LHS of the inequality.

Comment: @YNK: Thank you!  I corrected the error.